# Add comment form is showing error when try to add any comment in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Update: I have changed some code in views.py.

the basic source files [are here](https://pastebin.pl/view/a0a1fc38) and i am trying to include commment and reply system

views.py codes are give below:

```
from .models import Post,Comment
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect,render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


class PostList(ListView):
    model=Post
    template_name='home.html'
    context_object_name='post_list'
    queryset=Post.objects.all()

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model=Post
    template_name='post_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments']=Comment.objects.filter(post=self.object)
        context['comment_form']=CommentForm()
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        comment_form = self.get_form()
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(comment_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(comment_form)

    def form_valid(self, comment_form):
        comment_form.instance.post = self.object
        comment_form.save()
        return super().form_valid(comment_form)
```

when i execute the runserver it shows 
**AttributeError at /post/1/
'PostDetail' object has no attribute 'get_form'
**

the models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    reply=models.ForeignKey('Comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The post detail page is showing the comments and Comment form to add comment. but when i try to add any comment through the form it is showing error. i m running out idea. 
please let me know if you have any ideas. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it in class based views.

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

    class PostDetail(DetailView,FormMixin):
        model=Post
        template_name='post_detail.html'
        login_url='login'
        form_class=CommentForm
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse_lazy('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(BlogappDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['comments']=Comment.objects.filter(post=self.object)
            context['comment_form']=CommentForm()
            return context
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            comment_form = self.get_form()
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(comment_form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(comment_form)

        def form_valid(self, comment_form):
            comment_form.instance.post = self.object
            comment_form.instance.author=self.request.user
            comment_form.save()
            return super().form_valid(comment_form)
```

rest is same according to template and forms.

thanks again and keeping the answer for future help if anyone needs it

Answer (score 0):

In a class-based view you don't need to call the render function yourself

The method that you have put lots of your code in - `get_context_data` - shouldn't return the output of the render function.
It should simply return the context dictionary for your template

Also you don't specify the template in the `get_context_data`, it should be an attribute of the class `template_name='Post_detail.html'` just below or above `model=Post`

Also, as you are accepting form submissions it could work better for you to use a `FormView`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView

Apart from that - the way to get request in a class based view is with `self.request`.
However, if you use a FormView it will deal with all the places that you are currently using request.

Comment: i have updated the PostDetail view. will check on that please if it is ok?